# Pin lock screen - avoid pressing ok

Tags: lock-screens

Is there any way to avoid pressing ok on the stock Android pin screen? There was an option to do this in cyanogenmod (9?) for my Nexus S 4G but it's not in stock (which I'm using now, unrooted). Is there any way to make it so that pressing the correct code automatically unlocks it, without having to press ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason why pressing OK has to be done and cannot be avoided is this - the PIN number can be of any length of your preference, and by pressing OK that is signalling the intention that *There I have all the PIN digits entered, now Android, please verify!*

If there was a way to avoid pressing OK, that would impose the restriction on the length of the PIN digits used, once the length of digits is reached (for example *the PIN can be four digits long*), then it would be automatic, but unfortunately in this case, no, you do have to press OK.

Comment: So there's no way to do it at all on stock? Because like I said, cyanogenmod has this option.

Comment: It could be done by modifying the source in AOSP, and re-build the ROM for your handset :)